# Match one character inside set

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write regexp for verifying email addresses, I need to accept addresses with letters, numbers, underscores, periods, hyphens before '@' sign and the same set after it, but there mast be only one '@' sign in this address.

Currently I've stucked with this: `/^[\w\.\-@]*$/i`. I can't make it accept only one '@' sign: `{1}` doesn't works inside set and other ways I found wasn't ok too. So what is the way to match one character inside set?

Comment: You ca use: `/^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+$/`

Comment: @anubhava thank you, just what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use quantifiers inside character classes (i.e. `[@{1}]` will match either a `@`, `{`, `1` or `}`). What you need is to "unroll" your character class, split it into 2 parts taking out the character you want to restrict to only one occurrence between the two parts:

```
/^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+$/
```

Note this expression will require at least 3 characters, but that should be fine since email addresses can't be less than 3 chars long.

Also, the `/i` case insensitive modifier is redundant since `\w` matches both upper- and lowercase letters.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nG9nI9/1).